# SELECT where not in other table with COLLATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with a SQL Server statement.

I have 2 tables

**T1**

```
1
2
```

**T2**

```
1
2
```

I want to select from T1 where T1.2 not in T2.2. I tried this statement, but it's not working, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near keyword Collate

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.2 NOT IN (SELECT T2.2 FROM T2) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as
```

PS: I used `collate` because without it I got another error

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between arabic_ci_as and sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as

Comment: Depending on what column needs the collate, add it after the column. My guess would be `T2.2 COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually one collate values not entire querys.
Not sure as it's been a while since I worked with mssql but I think this should work for you.
I Collated both ends, might be a good idea if you change collation of any of the tables at some time, don't think you really want to have two diffrent collation in the same schema unless there is a very good reason for it.

```
SELECT * from T1 where T1.2 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not in 
(select T2.2 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT from T2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `T2.2` `2` here should be the column name the syntax is `tableName.coloumnName` not sure if that is what you mean.